# finding static scheduling of DAG for multiprocessors - library?

Tags: c++, python, parallel-processing, scheduling, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a graph of the dependencies of all tasks, and the costs of each task. Now I want to calculate a scheduling for a given amount of CPUs. I've found many papers on scheduling algorithms, optimal schedulers seem to be too expensive for my problem size (around 100 nodes) as it's an NP-hard problem. I'd settle for a heuristic, preferably one that has a bound how close it gets to the optimum. My problem now is: do I really have to code it myself?? This should have been solved many times before, it can be easily applied to project management, maybe there something exists?

If you happen to know a library in python that'd be perfect or the next best thing would be C++, otherwise i'd settle for anything else.

Comment: Do you really know the costs of the tasks?  Modern CPUs make predicting the cost of executing a bit of code very difficult, e.g., caches, synchronization costs, branch prediction, outside interrupts you cannot suppress, ...  You also have the problem of many nodes in your task graph may not be large enough to justify the overhead of scheduling them at all; they are better off being merged as work into neighboring nodes.  Unless you have very strong answers to these questions, I'll agree that an optimal algorithm won't help, as it has at best bad data on which to produce the "optimal" schedule.

Comment: I'm currently working on a concurrent framework and want to compare the performance of a forward scheduler that just runs whatever is ready to an optimal schedule. I have the cost for each task running on a single core, the cost of each task stays roughly the same when feeding in different data, so I hope to be able to pre-calculate a valid optimal schedule. Ignoring communication cost may be oversimplifying, but should be enough for at least a comparison, since communication exists also for the forward scheduler. Also, your comment cannot be "don't schedule at all", or is it? :)

Comment: No, clearly you have to honor the partial order implied by task graph if the dependencies are real.  And to the extent that some tasks are clearly much more costly than others, you can build a qualitatively correct schedule.  (Even if you don't do optimal, you can do branch-and-bound to get a best schedule with what you have).  But if the cost of the grains vary (e.g., each grain contains of loop of size determined at runtime) you might be just as well off with a dynamically determined schedule.  100 tasks means lots of opportunities throw cores at different tasks and still come out ahead.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. You mean the problem is small enough to get an optimal schedule using B&B? I didn't try yet, that might be possible. How do you mean I might come out ahead with a dynamic schedule? If task cost differ substantially between runs this is surely true, but for my particular problem task cost will be stable.

Comment: There's a trivial answer consisting of a linearization of the partial order, as a ridiculous upper bound.  You can surely run B&B with that starting bound until it terminates or you are sick of it running it, and take the best answer.  I don't know if you come out *ahead* with a dynamic schedule, but if the graph has lots of work it should do OK for a big part of it.  That's a least a lower bound your static scheduling algorithm should beat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty common problem.   It also shows up in hardware design. 
There has been a lot of work on algorithms to solve it.

If you are going to write something yourself, start by checking out "Hu's Algorithm".

If you just want a solution, these functions are built into architectural synthesis programs. 
Look at the Wikipedia pages on high level synthesis and logic synthesis. 
There are several professional tools that can handle this, if you can get access to them through school or work.

There are university programs you can often get for free that can also handle this problem. 
I'm not up-to-date on what is currently available.   An very old one is MIS II from Berkeley.   It's scripting language was Tcl, not Python.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/